# Wordpress Images Not Showing When FTP

Tags: multisite, ftp

Could someone explain or show me a link to learn why when you ftp an image to `uploads/sites/<blog_id>/` folder it does not show in the image gallery? Image gallery as in the one you see all your images in.

I'm using multi site. I could not find any documentation on why. Im transferring large amount of images onto a new sever.

Comment: Uploading the image is only one part of the process. When you add media to your site via the Media Library, it's actually added as an `attachment`, a built-in post type that carries with it a bunch of metadata. Simply FTPing images into the appropriate directory doesn't create the associated `attachment` post or set any of the metadata.

Comment: Oh wow! I never knew that. I guess I need to search for some sort of plugin to handle this.

Comment: A quick Google search led me to [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-from-server/), which might do what you need.

Comment: @PatJ, please make an answer out of those comments

Comment: @MarkKaplun -- done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uploading the image is only one part of the process. When you add media to your site via the Media Library, it's actually added as an `attachment`, a built-in post type that carries with it a bunch of metadata. Simply FTPing images into the appropriate directory doesn't create the associated `attachment` post or set any of the metadata.

A bit of quick Googling led me to the [Add from Server](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-from-server/) plugin, which might do just what you need.